# Convert RGB to HSL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, colors, rgb, hsl

I'm trying to get a HSL color value from my Database. Currently there is only a RGB value stored. Let's assume I got separate columns for rgb: red green blue with a number value 0-255 in them each.

Target result would be hue saturation lightness in the resultset, calculated from the rgb values. I've seen a lot of calculations but none of them seem easy enough to do in a query? Or I'm not deeply enough into SQL in general to know how to port something like a switch statement to SQL.

The best example for converting I've found is here: [How do you get the hue of a #xxxxxx colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732046/how-do-you-get-the-hue-of-a-xxxxxx-colour)

```
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b){
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    }else{
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return [h, s, l];
}
```

But I'm completely stumped for an answer on how to do something like this calculation in SQL.

After it not working quite correctly (the code sample above is incorrect from what I can see on wikipedia for conversion of the hue, as well as I needed the hue in full degrees 0-360 rather than between 0 and 1) I've started with the solution from Arth and got to this, I've decided to to a /255 on r,g,b beforehand because that is just easier to follow through from the above code sample:

```
CASE 
  WHEN r>=g AND g>=b  THEN ((g-b)/(r-b))*60
  WHEN g>r AND r>=b THEN (2-(r-b)/(g-b))*60
  WHEN g>=b AND b>r THEN (2+(b-r)/(g-r))*60
  WHEN b>g AND g>r THEN (4-(g-r)/(b-r))*60
  WHEN b>r AND r>=g THEN (4+(r-g)/(b-g))*60
  WHEN r>=b AND b>g THEN (6-(b-g)/(r-g))*60
END h,
CASE 
  WHEN r=g  AND g=b  THEN 0
  WHEN r>=g AND g>=b AND  (r-b)>0.5 THEN (r-b)/(2-r-b)          
  WHEN r>=g AND g>=b THEN (r-b)/(r+b)
  WHEN r>=g AND b>g  AND  (r-g)>0.5 THEN (r-g)/(2-r-g)
  WHEN r>=g AND b>g  THEN (r-g)/(r+g) 
  WHEN g>=r AND r>=b AND  (g-b)>0.5 THEN (g-b)/(2-g-b) 
  WHEN g>=r AND r>=b THEN (g-b)/(g+b)
  WHEN g>=r AND b>r  AND  (g-r)>0.5 THEN (g-r)/(2-g-r) 
  WHEN g>=r AND b>r  THEN (g-r)/(g+r)
  WHEN b>=r AND r>=g AND  (b-g)>0.5 THEN (b-g)/(2-b-g) 
  WHEN b>=r AND r>=g THEN (b-g)/(b+g)
  WHEN b>=r AND g>r  AND  (b-r)>0.5 THEN (b-r)/(2-b-r) 
  WHEN b>=r AND g>r  THEN (b-r)/(b+r)
END s,
CASE 
  WHEN r=g  AND g=b  THEN r
  WHEN r>=g AND g>=b THEN (r+b)/2
  WHEN r>=g AND b>g  THEN (r+g)/2
  WHEN g>=r AND r>=b THEN (g+r)/2
  WHEN g>=r AND b>r  THEN (g+b)/2
  WHEN b>=r AND r>=g THEN (b+g)/2
  WHEN b>=r AND g>r  THEN (b+r)/2
END l
```

Comment: What would those calculation look like?Try pseudo code.

Comment: Theres a function for it here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732046/how-do-you-get-the-hue-of-a-xxxxxx-colour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an absolute nightmare and not tested, but I've had a go:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN r=g  AND g=b  THEN 0
      WHEN r>=g AND g>b  THEN ((g-b)/(r-b))/6
      WHEN r>=g AND b>=g THEN ((g-b)/(r-g)+6)/6
      WHEN g>=r AND r>=b THEN ((b-r)/(g-b)+2)/6
      WHEN g>=r AND b>r  THEN ((b-r)/(g-r)+2)/6
      WHEN b>=r AND r>=g THEN ((r-g)/(b-g)+4)/6
      WHEN b>=r AND g>r  THEN ((r-g)/(b-r)+4)/6
    END h,
    CASE 
      WHEN r=g  AND g=b  THEN 0
      WHEN r>=g AND g>=b AND  (r-b)>0.5*255 THEN (r-b)/(510-r-b)          
      WHEN r>=g AND g>=b THEN (r-b)/(r+b)
      WHEN r>=g AND b>g  AND  (r-g)>0.5*255 THEN (r-g)/(510-r-g)
      WHEN r>=g AND b>g  THEN (r-g)/(r+g) 
      WHEN g>=r AND r>=b AND  (g-b)>0.5*255 THEN (g-b)/(510-g-b) 
      WHEN g>=r AND r>=b THEN (g-b)/(g+b)
      WHEN g>=r AND b>r  AND  (g-r)>0.5*255 THEN (g-r)/(510-g-r) 
      WHEN g>=r AND b>r  THEN (g-r)/(g+r)
      WHEN b>=r AND r>=g AND  (b-g)>0.5*255 THEN (b-g)/(510-b-g) 
      WHEN b>=r AND r>=g THEN (b-g)/(b+g)
      WHEN b>=r AND g>r  AND  (b-r)>0.5*255 THEN (b-r)/(510-b-r) 
      WHEN b>=r AND g>r  THEN (b-r)/(b+r)
    END s,
    CASE 
      WHEN r=g  AND g=b  THEN r/255
      WHEN r>=g AND g>=b THEN (r+b)/510
      WHEN r>=g AND b>g  THEN (r+g)/510
      WHEN g>=r AND r>=b THEN (g+r)/510
      WHEN g>=r AND b>r  THEN (g+b)/510
      WHEN b>=r AND r>=g THEN (b+g)/510
      WHEN b>=r AND g>r  THEN (b+r)/510
    END l
FROM table1
```

In conclusion, you are probably better off selecting the RGB values and running the conversion at the application level!

Comment: Thanks I'll test that :)
I'd probably go crazy with running the conversion in the application as I do want to sort by hue inside the Database too. In the end this will end up in a view and not bother me much (hopefully) and I just select the values from it.

Comment: @bardiir Rather than using a view, I'd probably denormalise one step and store RGB and HSL in the table side by side.. particularly if you are sorting by it!

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer doesn't seem to produce correct answers.

In case anybody needs correct computations, here is my version for PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RGB_TO_HSL 
( 
     _R int 
    ,_G int 
    ,_B int 
) 
RETURNS TABLE 
( 
     h float 
    ,s float 
    ,l float 
) 
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
        -- r,g,b 
        -- ,_max,_min 
        -- ,_delta 

        -- While it's more common to see integer values for the hue component in CSS, 
        -- the specification allows for floating-point numbers as well.
        -- You need to specify units (degrees or percentages) for hue, saturation, and lightness. 
        -- Omitting the units would result in an invalid/buggy CSS declaration.
        -- While the official CSS specification suggests using degrees (deg) for the hue, in practice, 
        -- CSS browsers often accept unitless values or even percentages for the hue.
        -- .myElement { color: hsl(262.5deg, 75%, 58%); }

         -- Hue: It is specified as an angle within the range 0 to 360 degrees. 
         CAST(ROUND(tSaturationHue.h, 0) AS float) AS h 

         -- Saturation and Lightness: These are specified as percentages. They range from 0% to 100%. 
        ,CAST(tSaturationHue.s * 100 AS float) AS s 
        ,CAST(tLightness.l * 100 AS float) AS l 
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT r, g, b 
        FROM 
        ( 
            VALUES ((_R / 255.0), (_G / 255.0), (_B / 255.0)) 
        ) AS RGB(r, g, b) 
    ) AS rgb_normed 

    CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                 MAX(val) AS _max 
                ,MIN(val) AS _min 
                ,MAX(val) - MIN(val) AS _delta 
                ,(MAX(val) + MIN(val)) / 2.0 AS l 
            FROM 
            ( 
                          SELECT r AS val 
                UNION ALL SELECT g AS val 
                UNION ALL SELECT b AS val 
            ) AS tUnion 

        ) AS tLightness 

    CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                 CASE 
                    WHEN _delta = 0 THEN 0.0 
                    ELSE _delta / (1.0 - ABS(2.0 * tLightness.l - 1.0)) 
                 END AS s 

                ,COALESCE
                ( 
                     60 
                     * 
                     CASE 
                        WHEN _delta = 0 THEN 0.0 
                        -- WHEN _max = r THEN  ((g-b) /_delta )%6 
                        WHEN _max = r THEN ((g - b) / _delta - FLOOR((g - b) / _delta / 6) * 6) 
                        WHEN _max = g THEN (b - r) / _delta + 2 
                        WHEN _max = b THEN (r - g) / _delta + 4 
                        ELSE NULL 
                     END 
                    ,666 
                ) AS h 
        ) AS tSaturationHue; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;



          SELECT  1 AS i, * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(0, 0, 0) 
UNION ALL SELECT  2 AS i, * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(1, 2, 3)
UNION ALL SELECT  3 AS i, * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(1, 2, 3)
UNION ALL SELECT  4 AS i, * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(1, 2, 3)
UNION ALL SELECT  5 AS i, * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(255, 255, 0)
UNION ALL SELECT  6 AS i, * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(120, 40, 255)
UNION ALL SELECT  7 AS i, * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(0, 255, 255)
UNION ALL SELECT  8 AS i, * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(255, 255, 255)
UNION ALL SELECT  9 AS i, * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(50, 100, 50) -- fsck 
UNION ALL SELECT 10 AS i, * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(49, 100, 50) 
;
```

And T-SQL/MSSQL:

```
ALTER FUNCTION RGB_TO_HSL 
( 
     @R int 
    ,@G int 
    ,@B int 
) 
    RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT 
         --r,g,b 
        -- ,_max,_min 
        -- ,_delta 

        -- While it's more common to see integer values for the hue component in CSS, 
        -- the specification allows for floating-point numbers as well.
        -- You need to specify units (degrees or percentages) for hue, saturation, and lightness. 
        -- Omitting the units would result in an invalid/buggy CSS declaration.
        -- While the official CSS specification suggests using degrees (deg) for the hue, in practice, 
        -- CSS browsers often accept unitless values or even percentages for the hue.
        -- .myElement { color: hsl(262.5deg, 75%, 58%); }

         -- Hue: It is specified as an angle within the range 0 to 360 degrees.
         ROUND(tSaturationHue.h, 0) AS h 
         -- Saturation and Lightness: These are specified as percentages. They range from 0% to 100%. 
        ,tSaturationHue.s *100 AS s 
        ,tLightness.l *100 AS l 
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT r, g, b 
        FROM 
        ( 
            VALUES 
            ( 
                 (@R / 255.0e) 
                ,(@G / 255.0e) 
                ,(@B / 255.0e) 
            ) 
        ) AS RGB(r, g, b) 
    ) AS rgb_normed 

    CROSS APPLY 
        (
            SELECT 
                 MAX(val) AS _max 
                ,MIN(val) AS _min 
                ,MAX(val) - MIN(val) AS _delta 

                ,(
                    MAX(val) 
                    +
                    MIN(val)
                )/2.0e AS l 
            FROM 
            (
                          SELECT r AS val 
                UNION ALL SELECT g AS val 
                UNION ALL SELECT b AS val 
            ) AS tUntion 
        ) AS tLightness 

    CROSS APPLY 
        (
            SELECT 
                CASE 
                    WHEN _delta = 0 THEN 0.0e 
                    ELSE _delta/(1.0e - ABS(2.0e*l-1.0e))
                END AS s 

                ,ISNULL
                (
                    60* 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN _delta = 0 THEN 0.0e 
                        -- WHEN _max = r THEN  ((g-b) /_delta )%6 
                        WHEN _max = r THEN ((g - b) / _delta - FLOOR((g - b) / _delta / 6) * 6)
                        WHEN _max = g THEN (b-r) /_delta + 2 
                        WHEN _max = b THEN (r-g) /_delta + 4 
                        ELSE NULL 
                     END 
                    ,666 
                ) AS h 
        ) AS tSaturationHue  
);

GO

-- Example usage:
-- DECLARE @R INT = 255, @G INT = 255, @B INT = 0;
-- DECLARE @R INT = 120, @G INT = 40, @B INT = 255; 
-- DECLARE @R INT = 0, @G INT = 255, @B INT = 255; 
-- DECLARE @R INT = 255, @G INT = 255, @B INT = 255; 
-- DECLARE @R INT = 0, @G INT = 0, @B INT = 0; 
-- DECLARE @R INT = 50, @G INT = 100, @B INT = 50;  -- fsck 
DECLARE @R INT = 49, @G INT = 100, @B INT = 50;  -- fsck 



SELECT * FROM RGB_TO_HSL(@R, @G, @B);




-- SELECT * FROM colors OUTER APPLY RGB_TO_HSL(color_r, color_g, color_b) AS t
```