# Set map marker to a custom color Android

Tags: android, colors, android-maps-v2, markers

I am making an app that adds pins to a map at certain points. I want the color of my pins to match the theme colors of our app. Sorry I'm really a noob

```
int color = Color.rgb(255, 201, 14);
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(40, -80);
Marker perth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
  .position(PERTH)
  .title("MY PIN")
  .snippet("MAGGIE EATS SNAKE SKINS")
  .draggable(true)
  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin))
  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.color)));
```

The .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.color))); does not work. It will not allow me to insert a custom color here. How can I do this? Thanks:)

Comment: Really a good question, but it seems the solution is to design the marker image and use it.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll just do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`defaultMarker()` method allows to set custom color, but only by providing hue value. According to android documentation:

> (Hue) Value must be greater or equal to 0 and less than 360

If you know Hex or RGB value of your app theme, you need to do some calculations (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732073/3224665) ) or simply use some [free online converter](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.htm). In your case hue value will be 47.

Also, there is no need to set .icon() property in your code twice.

Comment: when I am using the converter to get the HUE value for my color (#678E00), it gives me 3 values, (76,100,27.8), but I can only provide 1 number to the BitmapDescriptorFactory. Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: In your case, you need to convert HEX to HUE e.g using this [tool](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.html). What seems strange to me is that I got different values (103,142,0) for #678E00

Answer (score 1):

I have created this simple method to get marker of any color.

```
 public BitmapDescriptor getMarkerIcon(int color) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hsv[0]);
}
```