# Custom colored google maps marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to add a custom colored marker to a map. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27322075/832008) answer, which states that I need to feed a `BitmapDescriptorFactory` with a HUE color and give that to the `.icon()` method of the `MarkerOptions`, but when I am using a [converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.html) to get the HUE value for my color (#678E00), it gives me 3 values, (76,100,27.8), but I can only provide 1 number to the `BitmapDescriptorFactory`. Do you know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HSL (Hue, Saturation, Lightness) representation of your Hex color (#678E00) is 76, 100, 27.8.

This means that the Hue of your color is 76 which is the value that you need to feed to the `defaultMarker` function:

```
.defaultMarker(76)
```

Take into account that you can only set the Hue of the marker and the Saturation and Lightness won't be modified so your color will be different than the original `#678E00`

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, this was my issue, I used 76, but that`s not the color I needed. So is there no way to represent any color in the BitmapDescriptorFactory?

Comment: Using the `BitmapDescriptorFactory` you can only shift the hue, and as you can't touch the saturation and lightness you won't be able to get your desired color. You will need to use a custom marker icon