# Android use HEX color for google maps marker

Tags: android, google-maps, colors, marker

I want to use a custom hex color for google maps markers, but I saw you can only use hue colors from 0-360 and the 10 predefined ones. Is there any way you can change the marker color to be a hex one, or at least convert the hex value to hue so I can use that instead? I already know how to set a hue color to the marker, but not a hex one.

Comment: Here is an example on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3732187/1207156.

Comment: The answer is in javascript, which I don't need, but thank you anyway

Comment: Ok, I thought it would be easy for you to convert it into Java. I did the conversion for you and posted it below. If you compare the code you'll see that they are really similar.

Answer (score 5):

The following code shows an example. It's based on this great answer that uses JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732187/1207156

```
public class Convert {

    public static class Hsl {
        public double h, s, l;

        public Hsl(double h, double s, double l) {
            this.h = h;
            this.s = s;
            this.l = l;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String color = "#c7d92c"; // A nice shade of green.
        int r = Integer.parseInt(color.substring(1, 3), 16); // Grab the hex representation of red (chars 1-2) and convert to decimal (base 10).
        int g = Integer.parseInt(color.substring(3, 5), 16);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(color.substring(5, 7), 16);    

        double hue = rgbToHsl(r, g, b).h * 360;

        System.out.println("The hue value is " + hue);
    }

    private static Hsl rgbToHsl(double r, double g, double b) {
        r /= 255d; g /= 255d; b /= 255d;

        double max = Math.max(Math.max(r, g), b), min = Math.min(Math.min(r, g), b);
        double h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

        if (max == min) {
            h = s = 0; // achromatic
        } else {
            double d = max - min;
            s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);

            if (max == r) h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
            else if (max == g) h = (b - r) / d + 2;
            else h = (r - g) / d + 4; // if (max == b)

            h /= 6;
        }

        return new Hsl(h, s, l);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes they are indeed really similar. Thank you for your effort in converting this script :)