# Finding the Hue for a pixel in an image

Tags: image-processing, colors

I am trying to convert my rgb image to hsv. I am able to find the value and saturation but got into problem while dealing with hue. I searched for the formula for finding the hue value and got one here.

[How do you get the hue of a #xxxxxx colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732046/how-do-you-get-the-hue-of-a-xxxxxx-colour?lq=1)

But here also the accepted answer has discussed only 3 options.

1. R is maximum
2. G is maximum
3. B is maximum

(So this is **not** a duplicate question)

But what about other cases such as

```
R >= G > B or 
B >= G > R or 
G >= B > R etc
```

.

Clearly here there is no one value which is the maximum. So for clearing my doubt I searched google and found the following page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue

Here a table is given that is used for finding the hue value and 6 possible cases are also given. My question is

1. what are the values 2,4 or 6 in the formula given in the table and how are they calculated?
2. Why are only 6 cases possible(as shown in the table)? What about

   > ```
   > G >  B >= R or    
   > G >= B >= R or     
   > B >= R >  G or     
   > B >= R >= G etc.
   > ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let ImageMagick (installed on most Linux distros and available for OSX and Windows) tell you the answer by creating a single pixel RGB image and converting to HSL colorspace:

```
convert xc:"#ffffff" -colorspace hsl -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:

hsl(0%,0%,100%)
```

or

```
convert xc:"rgb(127,34,56)" -colorspace hsl -depth 8 txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,hsl
0,0: (96.0784%,57.6471%,31.7647%)  #F59351  hsl(96.0784%,57.6471%,31.7647%)
```

Comment: I want to do it manually using some programming language that's why I asked about the formulas.