# Custom Profile Colors

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, css-variables

**On Twitter, users can choose a custom color that is then used throughout their profile. How can I implement a similar functionality using HTML, (S)CSS and Angular 5?**

As is, I am doing for example:

```
<h1 style="color: {{user.color}};">
    {{ user.name }}
</h1>
```

This works, however the problems are:

- Clutters the html files with lots of `style` attributes
- I would like to be able to use the color differently for different media queries
- I would like to use *different shades* of the user's color throughout their profile

Normally, I would achieve this with SCSS using the `lighten()` and `darken()` functions. However, I obviously cannot do that when getting the user's color at runtime from the database and using the `style` attribute.

*How would you go about achieving custom profile colors for your users? Would you also use the style attribute, or is there an alternative (using Angular). How would you achieve variations of the user's color?*

*Can this be achieved with CSS Variables `var()`?*

Comment: maybe ngClass directive

Comment: One possible solution is to create color profiles that hard code these tints and shades into an array for easy access throughout your templates.

Comment: Have a look at CSS `var()` (CSS variables)

Comment: @SuperDJ How would I set the color though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the users picked HEX color and [transform](https://codepen.io/pankajparashar/pen/oFzIg) it to [hsl](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp). Than apply the style with the [ngStyle directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle). Example:

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'hsl(120, 100%, 50%)'}">...</some-element>
```

You can then tweak the lightness of the hsl background color (the third parameter).

Comment: Thank you, this is a great idea! I've used the conversion code found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732046/how-do-you-get-the-hue-of-a-xxxxxx-colour