# Change properties of input color element type

Tags: javascript, html

i want to change one property of `<input type="color"/>`
I try to do this by javascript but at the moment i can´t find a way/attribute to change the property, the property is marked by red circle in the image below, example put the value with 120.

[image].

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151013-00/?p=91371

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the hue of a #xxxxxx colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732046/how-do-you-get-the-hue-of-a-xxxxxx-colour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those params are usually referred to as `HSL` color values. They are specified with `hsl(hue, saturation, lightness)` in the CSS.

The CSS param can be used right away as a string to modify the necessary color.

If you want to edit the background, the below would help you:

```
document.getElementById('text').style.backgroundColor = "hsl(0, 0%, 100%)";
```

If you want a font color to be set, then use the below method:

```
document.getElementById('text').style.color = "hsl(180, 50%, 50%)";
```

You can change the style attribute depending on your need.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Since `<input type="color">` accepts a **value in HEX** (i.e: `#ffffff`),
Create a function that accepts the Windows HSL color ranges

- Hue 0 - 239
- Saturation 0 - 240
- Luminance 0 - 240

For simplicity sake, **use an in-memory canvas** to get the respective RGBA value from a `hsl()` color unit.
Than from a pixel data extract the R,G,B - and it's just matter of converting every 0-255 range to `.toString(16)` to get a HEX value:

```js
// Convert Windows Color Picker HSLu 239,240,240 to HEX
function winHSL2HEX(H, S, L) {
  const X = n => (n).toString(16).padStart(2,'0');
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  const HSL = `hsl(${~~(H/239*360)},${~~(S/240*100)}%,${~~(L/240*100)}%)`;
  ctx.fillStyle = HSL; ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
  const d = [...ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1).data];
  return "#"+ X(d[0]) + X(d[1]) + X(d[2]);
}

// Demo time
document.querySelector("#color_1").value = winHSL2HEX(160, 0, 120);
document.querySelector("#color_2").value = winHSL2HEX(67, 70, 120);
document.querySelector("#color_3").value = winHSL2HEX(239, 240, 120);
```

```html
<input id="color_1" type="color">
<input id="color_2" type="color">
<input id="color_3" type="color">
```

Now you can pass the desired `120` Lum value.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60689673/383904
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151013-00/?p=91371
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'value' argument:

```
<input type="color" value="#fa0a00">
```

If you have the color in an other format you must covert it to hex.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding HEX color value to set the "LUM" to 120 is `#7F7F7F` (because you're working here with HSL colors, and not RGB. So we need to convert it to HSL).
Then use the `value` attribute in the `<input/>` element to change the "propriety".
Example:

```
<input type="color" value="#7F7F7F"/>
```

But the "Hue" will be automatically set to `160`, and the R, G and B to `127`.

Comment: Saying *""LUM" to 120 is `#7F7F7F`"* is just like saying for RGB *"Blue is `#FFFFFF`"* which is odd, and as I pointed already Luminance in Windows color picker are represented as an inclusive range of 0 to 240. 120 is half that value that is *not* (like you said) `#7f7f7f`. HSL `160, 0, 120` is just simply `#808080` - just because **saturation** is at `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `HexToHSL` and `HSLToHex` found [here](https://css-tricks.com/converting-color-spaces-in-javascript/) you can convert the color to HSL, set the luminance value, and convert back to RGB to set the value of the form control.

On the control, the luminance varies from 0 to 240. Our converted color varies from 0 to 100, so before setting we divide by 240 and multiply by 100.

```js
document.getElementById("lumbutton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  var el = document.getElementById("colorsel");
  var color = el.value;
  var hsl = hexToHsl(color);
  var lum = parseInt(document.getElementById("lum").value);
  hsl[2] = lum * (100 / 240); // Change Luminance to typed value
  color = hslToHex(hsl);
  console.log(color);
  el.value = color;
});

function hexToHsl(H) {
  let r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
  if (H.length == 4) {
    r = "0x" + H[1] + H[1]; g = "0x" + H[2] + H[2]; b = "0x" + H[3] + H[3];
  } else if (H.length == 7) {
    r = "0x" + H[1] + H[2]; g = "0x" + H[3] + H[4]; b = "0x" + H[5] + H[6];
  }
  r /= 255; g /= 255; b /= 255;
  let cmin = Math.min(r, g, b),
    cmax = Math.max(r, g, b),
    delta = cmax - cmin,
    h = 0, s = 0, l = 0;

  if (delta == 0) h = 0;
  else if (cmax == r) h = ((g - b) / delta) % 6;
  else if (cmax == g) h = (b - r) / delta + 2;
  else h = (r - g) / delta + 4;

  h = Math.round(h * 60);

  if (h < 0) h += 360;

  l = (cmax + cmin) / 2;
  s = delta == 0 ? 0 : delta / (1 - Math.abs(2 * l - 1));
  s = +(s * 100).toFixed(1);
  l = +(l * 100).toFixed(1);

  return [h, s, l];
}

var hslToHex = function(hsl) {
  var h = hsl[0], s = hsl[1], l = hsl[2];

  s /= 100;
  l /= 100;

  let c = (1 - Math.abs(2 * l - 1)) * s,
      x = c * (1 - Math.abs((h / 60) % 2 - 1)),
      m = l - c/2,
      r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;

  if (0 <= h && h < 60) { r = c; g = x; b = 0; } 
  else if (60 <= h && h < 120) { r = x; g = c; b = 0; } 
  else if (120 <= h && h < 180) { r = 0; g = c; b = x; }
  else if (180 <= h && h < 240) { r = 0; g = x; b = c; } 
  else if (240 <= h && h < 300) { r = x; g = 0; b = c; } 
  else if (300 <= h && h < 360) { r = c; g = 0; b = x; }
  
  // Having obtained RGB, convert channels to hex
  r = Math.round((r + m) * 255).toString(16);
  g = Math.round((g + m) * 255).toString(16);
  b = Math.round((b + m) * 255).toString(16);

  // Prepend 0s, if necessary
  if (r.length == 1) r = "0" + r;
  if (g.length == 1) g = "0" + g;
  if (b.length == 1) b = "0" + b;

  return "#" + r + g + b;
}
```

```html
<input id="colorsel" type="color" value="#f08871"/>
<input id="lum" value="120">
<input id="lumbutton" type=button value="Set Luminosity value">
```