# Pass hex colors to sepia() & hue-rotate

Tags: css, reactjs

I am planning to change the color of a video. I want user to pass the the css hex color and the video need to inherit the color.

This is the screenshot of the original video color
[image: Original color image]

I use the filter css style like this =>  style={{ filter: 'sepia(20) hue-rotate(150deg)' }} to get blue color like this
[image: Color image]

But I want user to pass their favorite color and show that color in video. User can pass the hex color value. Is there any way that I can do this using the css in react

Answer (score 1):

Although sepia is sometimes defined as having a hue at 30° on the HSV color wheel, when applied as a CSS filter the result can vary anywhere from 30° to 60° depending on the input color.

However, in practice I've found that if you assume a hue of around 50° it works pretty well for faking a tint.

To do this, you first convert your input color from hex to HSV using something like this: [How do you get the hue of a #xxxxxx colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732046/how-do-you-get-the-hue-of-a-xxxxxx-colour)

Then, find the difference between the target hue and 50°. For instance, if the target is 210° blue, the difference is `210 - 50 = -160`.

Then use that difference as a `hue-rotate` value in your filter list, after first converting to sepia:

> `filter: sepia(1) hue-rotate(-160deg)`

Or, you can could use a `calc` and update the filter value inline, with something like:

> `filter: sepia(1) hue-rotate(calc(210deg - 50deg))`

(Note: You may need to adjust `saturate` or `contrast` to get the effect you want.)

(Also: make sure the version of React you are using supports css filters.)